# Is there any kind of "Intellisense" in CodeBlocks?

Tags: codeblocks, code-completion, allegro5

I was wondering if is there any kind of Intellisense behavour in CodeBlocks.
The reason I'm asking this is because I am coding using allegro 5 and can't get the code completion plugin to work with the allegro 5 library...
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allegro and Code::Blocks' Autocomplete feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995205/allegro-and-codeblocks-autocomplete-feature)